# Doctrine 2 choking on Postgres table columns

Tags: postgresql, orm, doctrine-orm

We are using Doctrine 2 for a new project and have run into an issue: Doctrine 2 chokes on Postgres table column names with spaces in them. For example, say there is a column named "Sales Person." While you and I know there should not be a space in the column name, it exists just the same. The databases were designed many years ago, and critical business systems run on them, so the column names cannot be changed. Is there a way around this issue without hacking Doctrine to handle this situation? If not, how would you propose solving this on the Doctrine end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like another badly coded ORM

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html

Says helpful things like: "You cannot use non [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ characters, they will break several SQL statements" and "Identifier quoting should not be used to enable the use non-standard-characters such as a dash" and "Schema-Tool will likely have troubles when quoting is used for case-sensitivity reasons".

Looks like it's another ORM that's been built by someone who doesn't want it to work with actual databases. Having columns with spaces etc. in them is not a brilliant idea but it's perfectly legal in SQL.

You've only really got three options:

1. Rename all the columns (or wrap everything in views).
2. Hack doctrine
3. Dump doctrine

None of them ideal, and I'm not sure what's going to be easiest in your case.

Comment: Great links! We have a couple of guys on the project trying to implement a hack, but it's messy. It's frustrating to have to use this and yet it doesn't even work properly with our databases.

Comment: It might be possible to use views depending on how extensive these sorts of issues are.  But I suspect you have already considered that.